# Android support library FloatingActionButton - padding on pre-lollipop devices?

Tags: android, android-support-design

This is my FAB definition:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_capture_action_show_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/c"
```

It seems that there's some extra padding when rendered on pre-lollipop devices and I can't seem to be able to remove it.

Lollipop rendering:

[image: lollipop]

Pre-lollipop rendering:

[image: pre-lollipop]

Any suggestions much appreciated..

Comment: Did you find the answer? Please share it here so it will be helpful for us who are facing same issue.

Comment: No answer yet - parked it for now.. I think I will just have to manually adjust the padding for pre-lollipop devices... which sucks..

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the way padding is implemented in the FAB on pre-Lollipop devices.

There's no way I know of to remove it on pre-Lollipop, but you can make it consistent (i.e. increase the padding on Lollipop and up) by setting `app:useCompatPadding="true"` on the FAB in the layout definition, or by using [setUseCompatPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#setUseCompatPadding(boolean)).

It behaves this way because of the way shadows are drawn.

Answer (score 0):

So I still don't know if there's an 'official' way to do this, but I ended up doing the following:

```
        if (!isLollipopAndAbove()) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tab.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            tab.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
```

oh and yes that was margin not padding that had to be changed